# Is there a different between the first Attahiyatulilah recitation and the last one of Salat

Tags: salat, tashahhud

Heard the last atayya on a salaat has addiditon du'ah after its recitation. Is that true and what's the du'ah.

Comment: That depends on the madhhab and each madhhab has chosen a certain version of at-Tashahud.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I think that the question is not about the versions of Tashahhud.

Comment: @Muslim yes I know that was just a side note.

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

After Attahiyat, aka Tashahhud, in the last rakaat of Salah the worshiper recites Salawaat, then makes duas, then performs Taslim saying Salaam to his right and left with which Salah ends. This is the only diffirence between the previous rakaats and the last rakaat in Salah consisting more than two rakaats. **Tashahhud, or Attahiyat, itself is always the same.**